# R - simultaneously create several columns with mutate

Tags: r

let's imagine you are doing something like this:

```
mutate(mtcars,
       ff1 = hp + wt*1,
       ff2 = hp + wt*2,
       ff3 = hp + wt*3,
       ff4 = hp + wt*4)
```

In this case we have just four new columns to create and it is quite easy to do it manually. However, imagine that you want to create 150 new columns in this way. It would be very tedious and time-consuming to write out all the individual `ff =` stuff. It would be the easiest if we could do something like this:

```
mutate(mtcars,
       ff = hp + wt*seq(1:150))
```

However, this doesn't work because of this thing:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `ff = hp + wt * seq(1:150)`.
✖ `ff` must be size 32 or 1, not 150.
```

So what is the proper syntax to achieve the desired output? Thanks.

Comment: You are right.  The issue was different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could loop over the sequence with `map`, then create the column with `transmute` (so that it returns only a single column) by taking the sum of 'hp' and the 'wt' multiplied by the looped value.  The `=` doesn't evaluate an expression on the lhs, so we use `:=` to evaluate (`!!`) an expression created with `paste/str_c` as new column name

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
map_dfc(1:150, ~ mtcars %>% 
  transmute(!! str_c('ff', .x) := hp + wt * .x)) %>% 
     bind_cols(mtcars, .)
```

---

Or using `base R`, use `outer` to return the product of 'wt' and the sequence as a `matrix` and add the hp column, create the new columns by assignment (`<-`)

```
mtcars[paste0("ff", 1:150)] <-  outer(mtcars$wt, 1:150) + mtcars$hp
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work great! Could I maybe ask you for more detailed explanation of the !! and := part because I am really not familiar with these operators.

Comment: @J.Doe hope the update helps you